# Echo-ing Only Available Database Result

Tags: php

I have this Associative Array :

```
$Fields = array("row0"=>"Yahoo ID", "row1"=>"MSN ID", "row2"=> "Gtalk ID");
```

on the other side, I have this SQL query :

```
SELECT YahooID, MSNID, GTalkID From UserTable WHERE Username = '$Username' LIMIT 1;
```

the result maybe vary, because some users only have Yahoo ID and some have others. for example if I have this result :

```
$row[0] = NONE //means YahooID = NONE
$row[1] = example@msn.com
$row[2] = example@gmail.com
```

then how to have this as an output (echo) :

MSN ID = example@msn.com

Gtalk ID = example@gmail.com

since Yahoo ID is not exist, then the result will be MSN and Gtalk only. 'MSN ID' and 'Gtalk ID' is variable from Associative Array, while 'example@msn.com' and 'example@gmail.com' from SQL result.

thanks!

Comment: are you looking for `isset()` or `empty()`?

Comment: Are you asking how to write an IF statement using `empty()` as a condition?  `if (!empty($row[0])) {...do something, like push to your $fields array...}`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: instead of IF, I'm trying to do LOOP. what I'm expecting as result is actually like this : $Result = array("MSN ID" => "example@msn.com", "Gtalk ID" => "example@gmail.com"); so later on I can echo that array as described on my post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Fields = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if (! empty($row[0])) $Fields['MSN ID'] = $row[0];
    if (! empty($row[1])) $Fields['GTalk ID'] = $row[1];
    if (! empty($row[2])) $Fields['Yahoo ID'] = $row[2];
}

foreach ($Fields as $k => $v)
{
    echo "$k = $v" . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: What's that PHP_EOL used for?

Comment: Just for a new line in the output.  PHP_EOL is the platform's new line constant.  It is like doing a "\n" or "\r\n" depending on the OS.  Good practice to use these.  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php